# Data validation list from custom function

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel

Is it possible to get the options for a data validation list from a custom function? For example, if a function were defined as

```js
/**
 * Some list.
 * @customfunction
 * @returns Some list.
 */
function someList(): any[][] {
    return [["hello", "world", "foo", "bar"]];
}
```

Can I achieve the following:

[image]

Obviously, the direct answer is seemingly "no" as it tries to interpret the function as a named range, but I'm hoping I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel currently doesn't support arrays directly - [UserVoice item here](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10665495-arrays-as-source-data-for-data-validation-pivotta) which prevent custom functions and xll/vba user defined functions from being used in this manner.  I'd add a comment to that item.

As a workaround, you could have a hidden sheet with a range reference/hidden name and use the data validation api to create the name. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-data-validation#list-validation-rule-type